# Need to produce two-faced three-vertex meshes

Tags: mesh, vertices, normals

Need to recreate a unique effect where two triangles share same verts but are flipped. It produces a normal effect that creates vegetation that always manages to properly angle lighting towards the camera.

I'm not super familiar with Blenders tools so I'm not sure if there's a way to do this already but a lot of posts I found before state that this kind of thing is treated as a bug when right now its a desired effect.

[image: Evaluated mesh: Vertex]

[image: Evaluated mesh: Face]

Resulting effect when exported two-face meshes used (Right side, Left is without this effect)

[image: Resulting effect when exported two-face meshes used (Right side, Left is without this effect)]